# Error when using @Query with EmbeddedId after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've upgraded my project to Spring Boot 3.0.1 from 2.7.6, It was working flawless, but know when I try deploying the project it's giving me the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityController' defined in file [C:\Users\fernando.lopes\OneDrive - Associação Educativa Evangélica\Workspaces\intellij\UniArch-Modules\UniArch-Security\target\classes\br\edu\aee\uniarchsecurity\controller\SecurityController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'centralSecurityService' defined in file [C:\Users\fernando.lopes\OneDrive - Associação Educativa Evangélica\Workspaces\intellij\UniArch-Modules\UniArch-Security\target\classes\br\edu\aee\uniarchsecurity\service\CentralSecurityService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6: Error creating bean with name 'scenarioRepository' defined in br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UniArchSecurityCoreApplication: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.UniArchSecurityCoreApplication.main(UniArchSecurityCoreApplication.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centralSecurityService' defined in file [C:\Users\fernando.lopes\OneDrive - Associação Educativa Evangélica\Workspaces\intellij\UniArch-Modules\UniArch-Security\target\classes\br\edu\aee\uniarchsecurity\service\CentralSecurityService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6: Error creating bean with name 'scenarioRepository' defined in br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UniArchSecurityCoreApplication: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scenarioRepository' defined in br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UniArchSecurityCoreApplication: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.edu.aee.uniarchsecurity.repository.ScenarioRepository.findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:55) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [FROM Scenario sc WHERE sc.useCase.pk = :useCasePk and sc.pk.id = :id]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [FROM Scenario sc WHERE sc.useCase.pk = :useCasePk and sc.pk.id = :id]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:760) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy161.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [FROM Scenario sc WHERE sc.useCase.pk = :useCasePk and sc.pk.id = :id]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [FROM Scenario sc WHERE sc.useCase.pk = :useCasePk and sc.pk.id = :id]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:747) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'id' of 'br.edu.aee.uniarchboot.subsystems.configurations.model.ConfigurationDomainPK'
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.SqmPathSource.getSubPathSource(SqmPathSource.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmPath.get(AbstractSqmPath.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.SqmEmbeddedValuedSimplePath.resolvePathPart(SqmEmbeddedValuedSimplePath.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.DomainPathPart.resolvePathPart(DomainPathPart.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.consumeIdentifier(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimplePath(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4808) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitIndexedPathAccessFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4755) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4724) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$GeneralPathExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6963) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:46) ~[antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:4.10.1]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParserBaseVisitor.visitBarePrimaryExpression(HqlParserBaseVisitor.java:671) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$BarePrimaryExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6437) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2105) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ComparisonPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5491) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1966) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5393) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1949) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5290) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:857) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:629) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:623) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1131) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:399) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'id' of 'br.edu.aee.uniarchboot.subsystems.configurations.model.ConfigurationDomainPK'
    ... 108 common frames omitted
```

I can't see where the problem is, becasuse I litteraly changed nothing. The funny thing is, the last line says the problem is on the class 'ConfigurationDomainPK', which is strange, because it haven any with relation with the entities affected by the error. It led me to think the class ConfigurationDomainPK' was the problem, I delete it for test purposes and the error just jumped from another classes but same cause, a query using a @EmbeddedId.

I changed the @Query to receive the ScenarioPK as parameter and it workred with no problems, but if I try to access the individual fields the error appears.

Here are the entities from the error:

```
public class Scenario extends CompositeEntity<ScenarioPK> {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ScenarioPK pk;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("useCase")
    @JoinColumn(name = "use_case_pk", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SCENARIO_USE_CASE"))
    @SearchableField(description = "SRH_USE_CASE")
    @DropCascade
    private UseCase useCase;

    @Column(name = "visible_name", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String visibleName;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean single;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean showOnMenu;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, name="restricted_access")
    private boolean restrictedAccess;
    
    private String description;
    
    private String image;
    
    @Column(name = "toolbar_image")
    private String toolbarImage;
    
    private Boolean toolbar;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "scenario_id"),
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "use_case_pk", name = "use_case_pk")})
    @DropCascade
    private Set<ScenarioEnvironment> scenarioEnvironment;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "scenario_action", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "use_case_pk", referencedColumnName = "use_case_pk"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "scenario_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "action_pk", referencedColumnName = "pk")},
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SCENARIO_ACTION_SCENARIO"),
        inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SCENARIO_ACTION_ACTION"))
    private Set<Action> actions;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @DropCascade
    private Set<ViewComponent> components;
    
    public Scenario() {
        this.setPk(new ScenarioPK());
        this.actions = new HashSet<>();
        this.scenarioEnvironment = new HashSet<>();
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    
}
```

```
public class ScenarioPK implements ICompositePK {
        
    private Long useCase;
    
    @SearchableField(description = "SRH_ID")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 40, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String id;

    public ScenarioPK() {
    }
    
    public ScenarioPK(Long useCase, String id) {
        this.useCase = useCase;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((useCase == null) ? 0 : useCase.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        ScenarioPK other = (ScenarioPK) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (useCase == null) {
            if (other.useCase != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!useCase.equals(other.useCase)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Long getUseCase() {
        return this.useCase;
    }

    public void setUseCase(Long useCase) {
        this.useCase = useCase;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```
public interface ScenarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Scenario, ScenarioPK> {
    
    @Query("FROM Scenario sc WHERE sc.useCase.pk = :useCasePk and sc.pk.id = :id")
    Optional<Scenario> findByUseCase_PkAndPk_Id(Long useCasePk, String id);

}
```

PS: The classes, CompositeEntity and ICompositePK are just bases calsses from our project, not related with the error at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This could be a bug. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Similar Error like the one above arises (after upgrading springboot version from 2.7.8 to 3.0.4) when the query uses embeddedId in the subquery section with a relation between the outer and the inner query. Thank you for any help.

I have provided 4 sample queries below. The fourth query - deleteCount4 breaks. Commenting out the fourth query results in the successful bootup of the application. I drilled down to the exception and here is the exact one thrown.

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2 WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId = u2.queryId AND id.userId=?1)]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2 WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId = u2.queryId AND id.userId=?1)]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
    ... 47 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple from-elements expose unqualified attribute : id
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SqmPathRegistryImpl.findFromExposing(SqmPathRegistryImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer$BaseLocalSequencePart.resolvePathPart(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.consumeIdentifier(
```

Code snippet on the interface with comments on what works and what doesn't work.

```
public interface SampleRepo extends BaseJpaRepo<AppUser, UUID> {

    public static final String COUNT_QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM";

    //No EmbeddedId - works fine
    @Query(value = COUNT_QUERY + " QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2"//
            + " WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id from ModelEntity WHERE id=u2.queryId)"//
    ) //
    public Long deleteCount1();

    //EmbeddedId Simple Query - works fine
    @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId=?1 AND id.userId=?2") //
    public Long deleteCount2(Integer id, UUID loggedInUserId);
    
    //EmbeddedId Simple Query in the SubQuery section - works fine
    @Query(value = COUNT_QUERY + " QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2"//
            + " WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.userId=?1)"//
    ) //
    public Long deleteCount3(UUID loggedInUserId);
    
    //EmbeddedId Query in the SubQuery section with relation between the outer and the inner query - Breaks
    @Query(value = COUNT_QUERY + " QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2"//
            + " WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId = u2.queryId AND id.userId=?1)"//
    ) //
    public Long deleteCount4(UUID loggedInUserId);
}
```

Model classes
QueryUser is annotated with @Entity

```
@Table(name = "query_users", schema = "studio")
```

and QueryUserId is annotated with @Embeddable

```
public class QueryUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private QueryUserId id;

    public QueryUser() {

    }

    public QueryUserId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(QueryUserId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}



public class QueryUserId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "query_id")
    private Integer queryId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

    public QueryUserId() {
        // Default construction needed for JPA
    }

    public Integer getQueryId() {
        return queryId;
    }

    public void setQueryId(Integer queryId) {
        this.queryId = queryId;
    }

    public UUID getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(UUID userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-03-07T22:00:01.495-05:00","@version":"1","message":"Application run failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"restartedMain","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleRepo' defined in io.kobai.studio.security.SampleRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Application: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Long io.kobai.studio.security.SampleRepo.deleteCount4(java.util.UUID); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long io.kobai.studio.security.SampleRepo.deleteCount4(java.util.UUID)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
    at io.kobai.Application.main(Application.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)\nCaused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Long io.kobai.studio.security.SampleRepo.deleteCount4(java.util.UUID); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long io.kobai.studio.security.SampleRepo.deleteCount4(java.util.UUID)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    ... 21 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long io.kobai.studio.security.SampleRepo.deleteCount4(java.util.UUID)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111)
    ... 33 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2 WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId = u2.queryId AND id.userId=?1)]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2 WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId = u2.queryId AND id.userId=?1)]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:760)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:126)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy141.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94)
    ... 39 common frames omitted\nCaused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2 WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId = u2.queryId AND id.userId=?1)]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueryEntity u1, Visualization u2 WHERE u1.id IN (SELECT id.queryId from QueryUser WHERE id.queryId = u2.queryId AND id.userId=?1)]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
    ... 47 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple from-elements expose unqualified attribute : id
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SqmPathRegistryImpl.findFromExposing(SqmPathRegistryImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer$BaseLocalSequencePart.resolvePathPart(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.consumeIdentifier(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimplePath(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4808)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitIndexedPathAccessFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4766)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4735)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$GeneralPathExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6972)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParserBaseVisitor.visitBarePrimaryExpression(HqlParserBaseVisitor.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$BarePrimaryExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6446)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2105)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ComparisonPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5493)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1966)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5395)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1949)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5292)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1220)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1133)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSubquery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4686)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitInPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2346)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitInPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$InPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5468)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1949)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5292)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1220)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1133)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:81)
    ... 51 common frames omitted\n"}
```

Comment: Issue Created: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1940